# Link from react-router-dom is not working properly with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `react-router-dom` and `Material-ui`

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a clickable row in table which routes to a specific path.

My code:

```
.map(client => (
  <TableRow key={client.id} component={Link} to="/">
    <TableCell>{client.name}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{client.type}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{client.bandwidth}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>))
```

Imports:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer'
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table'
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead'
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody'
import TableFooter from '@material-ui/core/TableFooter'
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow'
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell'
```

The solution which I found is `component={Link} to="/"` inside of `<TableRow />`

This all works fine until I have a look in the console of Chrome, where I get the error

```
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <a>.
```

Anything could help me with this. I am very new to material-ui, started only yesterday :-)

Thank you

Edit:
Full code

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
<Table size="small">
<TableHead>
<TableRow>
{headCells.map(((headCell) => (
<TableCell
key={headCell.id}
sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
>
{headCell.label}
</TableCell>
)))}


</TableRow>

</TableHead>
<TableBody>
{clients
.map(client => (
<TableRow key={client.id} component={Link} to="/">
<TableCell>{client.name}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{client.type}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{client.bandwidth}</TableCell>
</TableRow>))}

</TableBody>
</Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Comment: by any change, are you wrapping your table head in `a` tag ? as the error suggests you are wrapping your <TableHead> or one of its subcomponent in a tag

Comment: Ive added my full code above

Comment: `<TableRow key={client.id} component={Link} to="/">` line is the problem. Instead of this probably you can add an event listener

Comment: yeah i know that this line is a  problem. But is there a way to have it working like this? Or am I just trying to fix unfixable? Surely we can have a clickable row in table from material-ui and using react-router

Comment: In this scenario I think eventlistener should be the way to go, especially for table html tags

Answer (score 0):

You can export your component using `withRouter` from react-router-dom then on table row click function you can do `this.props.history.push('yourLink')`.

or like

```
<TableRow key={client.id}>
  <Link  to={"/"}>  
    <TableCell>{client.name}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{client.type}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{client.bandwidth}</TableCell>
  </Link>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Hey, I've seen this solution but it will remove the context menu (right click ability and open in new tab), right?

Comment: Still having the same problem. Error is still the same. `<Link />` will render as `<a>` and its causing the console error

Comment: What about you put `tablerow` as a child of link or maybe you should provide us a snippet and let us try on it?